# Remove duplicate code in query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, datacontext

I have this code :

```
list = _dataContext.myTable
    .Where(row => row.Label.Contains(myText))
    .OrderBy(row => row.Label)
    .Select(row => new MyClass
    {
        Field1 = row.Field1,
        Field2 = row.Field2,
        Field3 = row.Field3
    }).ToList<IMyClass>();

list = _dataContext.myTable
    .OrderBy(row => row.Label)
    .Select(row => new MyClass
    {
        Field1 = row.Field1,
        Field2 = row.Field2,
        Field3 = row.Field3
    }).ToList<IMyClass>();
```

As you see, I have duplicate code. Then I do this :

```
private List<IMyClass> CreateObject(IOrderedQueryable<myTable> list)
{
    return list.Select(row => new MyClass
    {
        Field1 = row.Field1,
        Field2 = row.Field2,
        Field3 = row.Field3
    }).ToList<IMyClass>();            
}

result = _dataContext.myTable
    .Where(row => row.Label.Contains(myText))
    .OrderBy(row => row.Label);
var finalList = CreateObject(result);
```

When I do this, the "Linq 2 SQL profiler" give me this warning :

> using a single data context in multiple hread is likely a bug.

I have this only when I use the `CreateObject` method

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you also getting it if you're implementing CreateObject as an extension method to IOrderedQueryable<T>? Most likely profiler error anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're making things more complicated than they need to be. You might be better off doing something like this:

```
// If suspendFilterByMyText is true, the Where() call will always return true.
bool suspendFilterByMyText = true;
list = _dataContext.myTable
    .Where(row => (suspendFilterByMyText || row.Label.Contains(myText)))
    .OrderBy(row => row.Label)
    .Select(row => new MyClass
    {
        Field1 = row.Field1,
        Field2 = row.Field2,
        Field3 = row.Field3
    }).ToList<IMyClass>();
```

This approach will work in both cases; you just have to set `suspendFilterByMyText` appropriately. Wrap it in a method and you will only have to write this code once.

Comment: && should be || or am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

Well there's this:

http://l2sprof.com/Learn/Alerts/CrossThreadSessionUsage

Put simply; if the class in which you are declaring and accessing these methods is synchronised correctly, then you can ignore this message. Is _dataContext global to your assembly or defined within your class? And are you sure your methods are called in the order you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
using a single data context in multiple thread is likely a bug.
```

It is just a warning and not an error, and it is right. Because the linq query runs only when you use the results or call ToList or ToArray e.t.c methods on your linq query.

So in your case the DataContext will be accessed in your method `CreateObject` when you call `.ToList()`.

You can simply ignore the warning, otherwise you have to keep your code duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link,
http://l2sprof.com/Learn/Alerts/CrossThreadSessionUsage

It says "Linq to Sql Profiler has detected a data context that is used in a different thread than the one it was opened on."
but the code you explained has no threading context, are you missing something?